# vector version of subset sum

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given a set of vectors $V = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_n\}, v_i \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Given a query $\vec{C} = (c_1, c_2), c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, how can one quickly verify whether if there exists a subset $ S\subseteq V$, such that $\sum_{v \in S}v == \vec{C}$ ?

And I have a constraint on query $\vec{C}$ which only two forms are allowed $(0, \sum_{v\in V} v[1])$ or $=(\sum_{v\in V} v[0], 0)$

A brute force approach can be treating every dimension independently first and then somehow figure out a way to intersect both feasible regions.

Comment: Your problem is at least as hard as subset sum (because the second coordinates could be all zero). Also you could encode your vectors $(x_1,x_2)$ as integers $x_1 + Mx_2$, with $M$ big enough. Then just solve as an ordinary subset sum problem. Now subset sum is NP-complete so finding a quick way may be nontrivial.

Comment: right, but I'm wondering if there is any better way to solve it so that it's not NP-complete.

Comment: Do you have any extra constraints e.g. on the values? Otherwise your problem is NP-complete because it contains SUBSET SUM as a special case (with second coordinates zero), and that is already NP-complete.

Comment: yeah, actually I have constraints on the values. $\vec{C}$ can only be $(0, \sum_{v\in V} v[1])$ or $(\sum_{v\in V} v[0], 0)$ .

Comment: can you please put all the constraints in the question, instead of having people ekeing them out of you in Q&A fashion.

Comment: The new constraint looks interesting, but the problem still contains the one-dimensional subset sum.